# Is there a way to make Identity Specification show up in the table designer next to the Allow Nulls column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity, ssms

I would like to be able to see the Identity Specification (not as worried about seed/increment) and hate having to scroll around on the column properties panel.

Is it possible to add a column next to Allow Nulls in the table designer for Identity Specification?  Specifically I am concerned with MS SQL Management Studio 2008.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you wanted but you can do it on a database diagram by right clicking the table -> Table View -> Custom and Modifying Custom to include the Identity Specification.

Answer (score 1):

I usually script the table to see all its properties. There are other things that are better vissible when a table is scripted as opposed to opened in designer, like keys and exact constraint definitions. I would recommend that you look at tables in their native format, not wrapped by designer.

Comment: I agree for looking at schemas this was more for when making quick tables for small projects its just an annoyance and out of the way to add the identity spec.